# Clases con "Public Members" ERROR! Expected Expression

Tags: c++

Quisiera encontrar el error o lo que le falta a mi código para que compile exitosamente.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    string firstName, lastName;
    int dob;
    int phoneNumber;
    int id;
    double overallGPA;
};

int main()
{   
Student Student1;

cout << "\t Student 1 Info:" << endl;
cout << "Student 1 ID: ";
Student1.id = 444444444;

cout << "Student 1 Phone Number: ";
Student1.phoneNumber = {828, 888, 8888};

cout << "Student 1 Date Of Birth: ";
Student1.dob = {11, 21, 1985};

cout << "Student 1 Overall GPA: ";
Student1.overallGPA = 3.45;

cout << "Student 1 First Letter of Last Name: ";
Student1.firstName = "T";

cout << "Student 1 First Letter of First Name: ";
Student1.lastName = "R";


return 0;
}
```

En las lineas `Student1.dob` y `Student1.phoneNumber` son un arreglo, pero no se como manejarlo con las clases.

Me sale el siguiente error en el terminal:

```
preLab.cpp:30:25: error: expected expression
        Student1.phoneNumber = {828, 888, 8888};
                               ^
preLab.cpp:33:17: error: expected expression
        Student1.dob = {11, 21, 1985};
                       ^
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Student
{
public:
    string firstName, lastName;
    int dob;
    int phoneNumber;
    int id;
    double overallGPA;
};
```

Lo primero, si todos los miembros de una clase son públicos, entonces mejor cambias `class` por `struct` y te ahorras el `public:`

```
struct Student
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    int dob;
    int phoneNumber;
    int id;
    double overallGPA;
};
```

> En las lineas Student1.dob y Student1.phoneNumber son un arreglo, pero no se como manejarlo con las clases.

La estructura que has creado no tiene esos campos como arreglos sino como variables al uso. Para crear arreglos tienes que usar o corchetes o memoria dinámica:

```
struct Student
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    int dob[3];
    int phoneNumber[3];
    int id;
    double overallGPA;
};
```

Y ahora ya si podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
Student1.phoneNumber[0] = 828;
Student1.phoneNumber[1] = 888;
Student1.phoneNumber[2] = 8888;
```

No se puede hacer lo que pretendes:

```
Student1.phoneNumber = {828, 888, 8888};
```

Ya que este mecanismo únicamente funciona durante la inicialización.

Comment: Ok! Gracias a tu respuesta pude resolverlo el issue. Ahora mi pregunta es, porque no puede ver los valores una vez ejecutado el programa?

Comment: @GabrielValedon Eso es porque no estás usando `cout`: `std::cout << Student.firtName << '\n';`

Comment: @GabrielValedon por cierto, si la respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla con un tick. Necesitamos mantener un porcentaje alto de respuestas acertadas para que el sitio funcione. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo al [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Gracias. Pude resolver los errores de los arreglos, pero con el "cout" no me funciona...

Comment: @GabrielValedon al igual que los valores tienes que almacenarlos con un índice... Para imprimir los valores has de recurrir al uso de índices: `for(int i=0;i<3;i++) std::cout<<Student1.phoneNumber[i];`